# Use of ni or wa for " I always eat with my older brother on monday"

Tags: particles, particle-は, topic

In my textbooks solution it says

> getsuyoubi ha itsumo ani to 
>   isshoni tabemasu

I thought it would be

> getsuyoubi ni

Thank you in advance

Comment: What context is given by your textbook? I don't think the English should be always translated like that.

Comment: Watashi wa itsumo getsuyōbi ni ani to issho ni tabemasu. Add I to the sentence.

Comment: @JACK the 私は you suggest may well be entirely redundant. Japanese is a 'pro-drop' language.

Comment: I wanted to demonstate getsuyoubi ni. Getsuyoubi ha doesn't sound right.

Comment: @JACK 月曜日は is absolutely OK and indeed preferable in certain contexts. You can also "demonstrate 月曜日に" without using 私は; the sentence 
いつも月曜日に兄と一緒に食べます is comprehensible. Just saying "Add I to the sentence" isn't clear advice. Further, please refrain from answering in the comments -- if you want to answer a question, answer it using the answer box. Use the comments for clarifications or discussion of the question.

Comment: Apparently ha and ni can both be used.

Comment: @henreetee, in which context is ha preferred? The context of the book was that he declined an offer to eat pizza, because always eating with his brother on Mondays

Comment: @Ciff -- see answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first of all, the sentence （私は）月曜日にいつも兄と一緒に食べます。 is grammatically totally fine and would be comprehended in the context you give. This would probably best structurally translate as

> "I usually/always eat with my brother on Mondays"

However, partly because Japanese is a pronoun-drop language, and partly because of the situation -- where the speaker has been asked about going for pizza (presumably on a Monday) -- 月曜日**は**いつも兄と一緒に食べます might well be preferable here.

The reason for that is that he's focusing on the concept of Monday, so it makes sense to make it the topic/discourse of the conversation. In comparison to the above sentence, you'll thus get a structural translation of something closer to

> "On Mondays, I usually/always eat with my brother".

Using は thus makes it a bit clearer that it's the pizza invitation **being on a Monday** that is the issue as to why he can't go, which is appropriate for this context.

Hope that helps.